# What does an asynchronous server mean?

Tags: apache2, lighttpd

I am reading a journal, it stated

> Lighttpd is asynchronous server, and Apache2 is a process-based
>   server.

What does this actually mean? 
Which server will you recommend for RasPi in purpose of monitoring purposes.

Thanks.

Comment: You should try to google a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/11/nginx-vs-apache/) website for a detailed explanation.

In the traditional thread-based (Synchronous) models, for each client there is one thread which is completely separate and is dedicated to serve that thread. This might cause I/O blocking problems when process is waiting to get completed to release the resources (memory, CPU) in hold. Also,creating separate processes consumes more resources.

Asynchronous servers do not create a new process or thread for a new request. Here the worker process accepts the requests and process thousands of it with the implementation of highly efficient event loops.`Asynchronous` means that the threads can be executed concurrently with out blocking each other. It enhances the sharing of resources without being dedicated and blocked.